# Visual Studio Team Services - how to change language?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I use Visual Studio Team Services. I goto - My Profile - Locale - choose another language. But the language in the browser there is in English. How to change language in Visual Team Services?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Brian Harry's Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/10/28/visual-studio-online-is-in-europe.aspx) about Microsoft's first non-US hosted instance of Visual Studio Online:

> Although we have our first instance in a non-US, non-English speaking
>   region, **we do not yet support a localized experience for VS Online.** 
>   You can enter data in any language you wish but the UI for VS Online
>   is currently English only.  **This is something we expect to begin
>   addressing sometime next year.**

*Emphasis mine*.

Comment: It's 2017 :((((((

Comment: as little workaround, you can create your process template inherited from Agile,Scrum etc. In that process you can change some tiltles for workitems, queries and then easyly migrate your project to inherited process.

Comment: It's 2018 :((((((

Comment: It's 2019 :((((((

Comment: It's 2020 :((((((

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem where my TFS online was displaying in French rather than English even though other sites that I had been on were displayed in English. I discovered that my language had been set to French in Chrome and when I changed it back to English TFS also changed. So basically if you want to change the language of TFS online just change the default language in your browser!

The reason this works is that a lot of new web applications which are localised will look at the language settings for your browser and use that information to decide what language the website should be displayed in.

Source: I work with web applications that use this technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage VS Team Explorer locales here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
```

For example, you can rename folder with current team explorer locale to anything else (be sure to shutdown VS). After that locale will be switched to default (en-us).